# Is it guaranteed that the beginning of process output will be read asynchronously in C#?

Tags: c#, process

In the following sample to capture standard output for a process, since I can only begin to capture the output data after the process is started, how can I make sure it won't miss any output between calling `Start()` and `BeginOutputReadLine()`?

```
    void StartProcess()
    {
        var process = new()
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "console_program.exe"),
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            },
        };
        process.OutputDataReceived += MyProcess_OutputDataReceived;
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    }

    void MyProcess_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        File.AppendAllText($"output_pid_{((Process)sender).Id}.txt", e.Data + "\r\n");
    }
```

Comment: I think that it is sychton. The inter face between process and console will be redirected from the start bevor the program starts

Comment: @nbk Could you point me to some article to explain sychton? I can't find info about it.